# Which Javascript platform/framework to use for connecting two API's?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, google-chrome

I am tasked with connecting two API's to work with each other and I thought this would be the perfect opportunity for me to learn JavaScript.

The goal/task it outlined:

- Two separate systems each which have an separate API: 1. Room Booking System | 2. Chat Bot which talks to users (built a chat flow on talking to a user about booking a room)
- What needs to happen

  - Chat bots will speak to a client/user and ask him about room booking, it will offer to help the user book a room, it will gather all the details needed before passing onto the next API e.g. date, time, length of stay, number of seats, catering
  - The API for the booking system, I need to parse on the data from the chat bot stored in a .JSON to the booking system and then return the available rooms again stored in a .JSON to the Chat Bot which will list the available rooms, let the user select which one and then again post back to the room booking system which will return a confirmation

So I guess I need to use a bunch of POST requests and extract and send information of .JSON files.

I am very new to JavaScript, reading Eloquent JavaScript right now and watching tutorials to get my head around it, but once this is built it needs to run on a live server? so anyone can access use the room booking system via the chat bot.

Thank you

Comment: You shouldn't do something like this in `Javascript` but rather perform client interaction through it and handle all the logic on backend service in another language such as `Java` for example

Comment: Really? how come if I could ask to help me gain understanding? Thank you

Comment: Because making 2 APIs work together shouldn't be done through `Javascript`, making a bunch of _requests_ will have very bad impact on user experience and will make your website run very slow. Instead, group the data in 1 JSON object, send it to your web service (backend) which should then handle everything else and return a response once the processing is complete.

Comment: @Ante server side javascript is totally fine to build an API.
The most used framework is [express](https://expressjs.com/), you can find tutorials everywhere, here is [one](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/building-a-simple-node-js-api-in-under-30-minutes-a07ea9e390d2)

Comment: @GabrielBleu When you say `Javascript` it's a reference to _Frontend Javascript_, if you are talking about _Backend Javascript_ it's called `NodeJS` and shouldn't be flagged with `javascript`

Comment: Backend JavaScript is still JavaScript, the tag is fine. Please don't use code formatting for language names, they're not code.

Comment: @GabrielBleu so i'm fine to do this with express and not Java? Was really keen on learning Javascript hence I wanted to use it. From what I understand though i'm not building an API, just connecting two

Comment: Sure, dealing with JSON is really easy in node.

Comment: @GabrielBleu Thank you! really appreciate it